# TCP server not receiving all bytes send

Tags: python, tcp, tcpserver

The client is sending a png file to the server. the server never receives the last bit of data. The server is also waiting on more bytes to be received but they never get send? Any ideas what is causing this?

EDIT: changing some code from the answers. The problem proceeds though the server is waiting for data that never gets received

client code:

```
    if server_command == "take screenshot":
        pyautogui.screenshot("screenshot.png")
        filename = "screenshot.png"
        with open(filename, 'rb') as file:
            bytec = client.sendfile(file)
            print('Sent', bytec, 'bytes.')
        print("pic send")
```

client output:

```
Sent 177777 bytes.
```

server:

```
if msg == "take screenshot":
    with client.makefile("rb") as src, open("received-image.png", "wb") as f:
        data = src.read()
        f.write(data)
        print('Read', len(data), 'bytes.')
```

server output:

```
connected to ('192.168.2.140', 50418)
command: take screenshot
{hangs here waiting for ever}
```

Comment: What do you mean by _"the last bit of data"_? It cannot possible be one *bit*. Also, did you try not handling 1KB chunks, but taking the whole image into memory?

Comment: i mean like the last chunk of data sometimes is 50 kb sometimes 40 etc... I did not I will try doing it.

Comment: How are you expecting the server to know when it has read the last byte of the file? Also, did you confirm that it's the last bit of the file the server isn't getting, not the first bit of the file?

Comment: that's actually a pretty good point, I didn't. I managed to fix the problem by just adding a timeout. The last byte if the file is being received successfully

Answer (score 0):

I am unsure what is the reason to the file not being completely read, given your snippet. However, you should not be using the low-level socket functions given your implied use case. Use `socket.sendfile()` and `socket.makefile()` respectively:

Sender:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3

from socket import socket


def main():

    with open('srcfile', 'rb') as file, socket() as sock:
        sock.connect(('localhost', 5000))
        bytec = sock.sendfile(file)
        print('Sent', bytec, 'bytes.')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Receiver:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3

from socket import socket


def main():

    with socket() as sock:
        sock.bind(('localhost', 5000))
        sock.listen()

        while True:
            conn, addr = sock.accept()
            
            with conn.makefile('rb') as src, open('recfile', 'wb') as dst:
                data = src.read()
                dst.write(data)
                print('Read', len(data), 'bytes.')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```